# C++ noexcept declaration changes template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, noexcept

I was tinkering to confirm the example on page 91 of Effective Modern C++, and I ran into what seems to be a strange issue. This code

```
template<typename C>
void doStuff(C& a, C& b) noexcept(noexcept(doStuff(a.front(), b.front()))) {
    std::cout << "container version" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void doStuff<int>(int& x, int& y) noexcept {
    std::cout << "int version" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    vector<int> v2 = {4, 5, 6};
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    doStuff(x, y);
    doStuff(v1, v2);
}
```

Gives me an error like

> error: request for member ‘front’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type
>   ‘int’  void doStuff(C& a, C& b) noexcept(noexcept(doStuff(a.front(),
>   b.front()))) {

So, it seems like the top version of doStuff is being called, even though a.front() and b.front() should be returning references to ints. If I remove all the noexcept declarations from the code, I get the expected output.

This is with gcc 5.4.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that templates are a compile.time feature. When the first version of the `doStuff` function is defined, the compiler doesn't know anything about the specialization for `int`.

Comment: There's also the problem that `doStuff` has not been declared when it is first used in the `noexcept` specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, when the name lookup at this point:

```
template<typename C>
void doStuff(C& a, C& b) noexcept(noexcept(doStuff(a.front(), b.front()))) {
//                                         ^^^^^^^
```

will just find one `doStuff()`: your function template. The specialization hasn't been declared yet, so it isn't considered.

First thing to do is to simply avoid specializations. They're awkward. But then the real fix would be to stick in an extra empty type solely for argument-dependent lookup purposes. This will add a dependent name to the `noexcept` lookup that will delay invocation until instantiation:

```
namespace N {
    struct adl { };

    void doStuff(adl, int& , int& ) noexcept {
        std::cout << "int version" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename C>
    void doStuff(adl, C& a, C& b) noexcept(noexcept(doStuff(adl{}, a.front(), b.front()))) {
        std::cout << "container version" << std::endl;
    }
}

template <class C>
void doStuff(C& a, C& b) noexcept(noexcept(doStuff(N::adl{}, a, b)))
{
    doStuff(N::adl{}, a, b);
}
```

Comment: Does the `int` overload really have to be first?  Isn't the `doStuff` in the `noexcept` specifier a dependent symbol, meaning it isn't resolved until instantiation?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, this will fail for `C=std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Whoa, how does that work?  `adl` isn't a dependent name, is it?

Comment: OK. That works. I naturally assumed it had something to do with the specialization not being declared yet, but I knew there had to be a correct way to handle these kinds of scenarios given that I was aping something in the standard lib.

Comment: Hmm. This works, but I'm not sure how. I was assuming the use of a namespace was at least partly responsible for incurring the needed delay, but it still works without the additional namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Template specializations are not overloads.  Your specialization for `doStuff<int>` is not an overload of `doStuff<C>`, it is a specialization.  So overload resolution doesn't consider it, template instantiation will consider it, if the original is selected by overload resolution.  Replace your specialization with an overload (non-template, taking two `int&`s)

```
void doStuff(int& a, int& b) noexcept;
```